# handling click events on <p>s inside a div with jquery

Tags: jquery, events, html

I have the following html:

```
<h1 id="0000">A Title</h1>
<p id="0001"> Some text</p>
<p id="0002"> Some more text</p>
[...]
<p id="0539"> Last piece of text</p>
```

and this jquery code that handles click events on p:

```
$("p").click(function(){            // FUNCTION FOR CLICK ON <P>
    // do some stuff with text in <p>
});
```

Now I need to change the html to:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <h1 id="0000">A Title</h1>
    <p id="0001"> Some text</p>
    <p id="0002"> Some more text</p>
    [...]
    <p id="0539"> Last piece of text</p>
</div>
```

The problem is that with the changed html code when I click on a p an event for click on div is generated so the code for click on p is not executed. Is there some way that the program handles the click events on p(s) inside the div(s)?

Comment: <<The problem is that with the changed html code when I click on a p an event for click on div is generated so the code for **click on p is not executed** .>> This is wrong! Have you tested your code?

Answer (score 1):

To get the event of the `p`s inside the `div`s, use

```
$('div > p').click();
```

Of course, if you have also set up an event handler for the click of the DIV that will be triggered as well.

Comment: I don't know why but this code did not work. I had to use the code if $(e.target).is('p') instead